# Add Vector Street Name Labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, layers, vector

I'm a newbie with GeoData Processing and Map Making. I'm doing a city map for someone and I've got the vector layers in with the polygons and the lines, but I need the street names. How do i make a vector layer that shows the street names?

Some additional Specs: I'm using QGIS with OSM data. I also run a Mac with OS X 10.11.6 aka "El Capitan". I do not have access to a PC.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Hi Underdark, Sorry, I'm really really new, didn't know that. just asked a new question, did put more complete info with a screen shot?

Comment: I want to say QGIS labelling of curved linear features is a no-no. The Curved roads I have been working on cannot take "Curved" labelling for one or two reasons not known to me. I have set the maximum allowable angles for characters to bend with i,e. internally 25 degrees and externally up to 95 degrees to still no avail. Am really disappointed!

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the layer that you are trying to label-> then go to properties->there will be a 'Labels' tab on the left side of the properties window that you will click on. From there you can choose which field that you want to label the layer with (in your case street names). The layer labeling settings is quite useful because you can customize the labels in a way that best suits your data. You can customize your labels text, formatting, buffer, background, shadow, placement, and even rendering.

Here is a link that can help you more with labeling:

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/ca/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html